# Given $\iint_D \arctan \frac y x \, dx \, dy $ where $D = \{(x, y):1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4, x \le y \le \sqrt3x, x \ge 0 \}$. Move to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

> Given $\iint_D \arctan \frac{y}{x} \, dx \, dy $ where $D = \{(x, y):1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4, x \le y \le \sqrt3x, x \ge 0 \}$. Move to polar coordinates.

I stuck with finding $\theta$.

I know that $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, and in this case, $1 \le r \le 2$,

But I'm not sure what the second condition, $x \le y \le \sqrt3x$ and $x \ge 0$ means in this context, and how to use the to find $\theta$.

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634985/given-integral-iint-d-ex2-y2-dx-dy-in-the-domain-d-x-y/634991#634991) , `T. Bongers` has find that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ using the second condition, but I didn't understand how did it helped him.

So again, how can I find $\theta$ using these two conditions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using polar coordinates, $$x=r\cos(\theta)$$ $$y=r\sin(\theta)$$
From $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 4$, then $$1\leq r^2\leq 4 \implies 1\leq r\leq 2$$
Also we are given $x\leq y\leq \sqrt{3} x$, which means
$$r\cos(\theta) \leq r\sin(\theta) \leq \sqrt{3} r \cos(\theta)\implies 1\leq \tan(\theta)\leq \sqrt{3}\implies \frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta\leq \arctan(\sqrt{3})$$
Note that we can divide $r\cos(\theta)$ without flipping the inequalities because $x\geq 0$.

P.S. Isn't the condition $x\geq 0$ redundant since 
$$x\leq \sqrt{3}x\implies x\geq 0$$

Comment: Thank you so much! How did you get that: $1\leq \tan(\theta)\leq \sqrt{3}\implies \frac{\pi}{4}\leq \theta\leq \arctan(\sqrt{3})$??

Comment: @user1798362 Consider applying $\arctan$ on $$1\leq \tan(\theta)\leq \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: I didn't know it's legal .. is it legal to apply sin, cos and tan on all sided as well?

Comment: @user1798362: The arctan function is an increasing function over $[\pi/2,\pi/2]$